# Dynamic TSQL query with nested looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, adodb

I have built an Intranet-based quiz systm using SQL server as the backend. The quiz scores are stored in separate tables, one per quiz. Staff will have access to only some or all of the quizzes, depending on their position.
I am trying to determine the best way to run a query that will total up or sum the number of quizzes each person has completed, and compare it to a pre-determined number of quizzes assigned to them. Once the two numbers match, they are considered complete and I can export the final results to another DB.

I tried using a VBS loop to loop through the quiz tables and check each one's score, but I can't seem to get it to work properly since it kind of relies on looping through each staff member record, then having to loop again through all the table names assigned to each. I end up looping the initial query and not the secondary query in order to get the count:

```vb
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.CursorLocation = 3

rs.Open "Select v.emp_num, v.position, p.group_id From ValidApplicants as v, Positions as p Where v.complete = 0 and v.notified = 0 And v.position = p.Position", conn
RSCount = rs.RecordCount

i = 0
Do until i = RSCount
    strempNum = rs("emp_num")
    strPosition = rs("position")
    strGroupID = rs("group_id")

    Set rs2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs2.CursorLocation = 3

    rs2.Open "Select quiz_name, tblname, quiz_code From quizfilter Where group_id in (1, "& strGroupID &")",conn
    recCount = rs2.RecordCount

    x = 0
    Do until x = recCount
        strQuizName = rs2("quiz_name")
        strTable = rs2("tblname")
        strCode = rs2("quiz_code")

        Set rez = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rez.CursorLocation = 3

        j = 0
        Do until j = recCount
            rez.Open "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "& strTable &" WHERE 
            pass_fail = 1 And employee_num = 7275) AS SumCount"
            j = j + 1
        Loop

        Set rez2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rez2.CursorLocation = 3
        rez2.Open "Select quiz_count From QuizGroups Where group_id = "& strGroupID &"",conn
        if not (rez2.eof) then
            strQuizCount = rez2("quiz_count")
        end if

        rs2.MoveNext
        x = x + 1
    Loop

    if not users_eof then
        for record=0 to UBound(dataArray,2)
            strtheCount = dataArray(user_score,record)
        Next

        if (strtheCount = strQuizCount) then
            Wscript.Echo "Count is "& strQuizCount &""
        end if
    end if

    rs2.close
    set rs2 = nothing

    rs.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, maybe there is a way to achieve this via a dynamic query within a SQL stored procedure?

Many thanks

Comment: You have a fundamental design flaw in your database that you **must** fix first. You have dynamic table names. Don't do that. Instead of a separate table per quiz, make a single table called `quizzes` (or something like that) and put the columns `quiz_code, pass_fail, employee_num` in there. Before you continue working on this, make that change.

Comment: It is also time to learn how to use ANSI-92 style joins they have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea Tomalak,
I managed to get this working by updating all quiz scores to a common table, which I can reference now to determine if each user has completed the required number of quizzes.

I appreciate the help!